# Determine if a string is English

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

Is there a library where I can simple call a method on a string to find out if it is non-English? I'm trying to only save English strings and the incoming stream of strings has plenty of non-English in them.

Comment: What's 'non-English'? Is "Save the harbor!" English? Is "c u l8r"?

Comment: English English, or American English? "save the harbour!" ;-)

Comment: I think `I can simple call a method on a string` as well as `if it is non-english` is non-English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [linguo](https://github.com/NARKOZ/linguo#readme).

```
"your string".lang
# will return "en" for english strings
```

*Disclaimer: I'm the creator of this gem.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use GoogleTranslate API with the RailsBridge for it - http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware... but you could get this list into an array (http://www.langmaker.com/wordlist/basiclex.htm) and then match the string's words against it... Decide on some percentage as good, and go from there.

You could even use bayesian algorithm here to mark those words as "good" and learn from there, but that might be overkill.